# How can I redirect to home as soon as i get url?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm trying to use my company SSO(Oauth 2.0) Service,and I pass the url to the oauth service and

then I get the url with a code to get access token from front side, and then I pass the `fetch`

the code from client side url to backend server with the post, and then I get the code in server

side and redirect to the other url param in server side, i can get the user's information to client and server.

However, the client side URL  show the code that i sent , so I want to know how to get rid of it.

and I searched a solution that i can redirect the page to another page, but I do not know how to .

and I want to know what i was doing is right way .

Thank you in advance.i hope it's not bad explanation

this below is what i tried :

## client Side

```js
  var client_id =
    "client_random_id";

  var state_val = "RANDOM_STATE";
  var redirectURI = "http://localhost:3000";
  let api_url =
    "https://www.??????/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" +
    client_id +
    "&redirect_uri=" +
    redirectURI +
    "&state=" +
    state_val;

  const logout = `https://www.??????/oauth2.0/Logout?client_id=${client_id}&logout_redirect_uri=${redirectURI}`;
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const [userinfo, setuserinfo] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/create", {
      method: "post",
      body: queryParams,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setuserinfo(json);
      })
      .then("<Redirect to={routes.home.path}/>")
      .catch(ex => {});
  });
```

## Server Side

```js
app.post("/create", function (req, res) {
  const code = req.body.code;
  res.redirect(`/callback/?code=${code}`);
});

app.get("/callback", cors(), (req, res) => {


  if (req.query.code !== null && req.query.code !== undefined) {
    var token_url = "https://www.?????.kr/oauth2.0/token";
    var options = {
      url: token_url,
      method: "POST",
      form: {
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        code: req.query.code,
        state: req.query.state,
      },
    };

    
    request(options, function (error1, response1, body1) {
      if (!error1 && response1.statusCode == 200) {
        var tdata = JSON.parse(body1);
        var options2 = {
          url: "https://www.??????/oauth2.0/resource",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + tdata.access_token,
          },
        };
        request(options2, function (error2, response2, body2) {
          if (!error2 && response2.statusCode == 200) {
            var rdata = JSON.parse(body2);
            res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/json;charset=utf-8" });
            res.end(body2);
          } else {
            res.status(response2.statusCode).end();
            console.log("error2 = " + response2.statusCode);
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.status(response1.statusCode).end();
        console.log("error1 = " + response1.statusCode);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: `.then("<Redirect to={routes.home.path}/>")` <- This looks wrong. `.then` is expecting a function, not a string

Comment: I should try to find a way using as a function ! Thank you Sir . !

Comment: If you want to return that string from the function, then you should do ``.then(() => `<Redirect to={${routes.home.path}}`)``

Comment: **Sidenote**: Your `useEffect` has no dependency array. If you just want it to run once, pass an empty array as the second parameter. Otherwise it will run at every render

Comment: oh right ! that's why !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to change this part `.then("<Redirect to={routes.home.path}/>")`

to something like this

```
.then(() => {
    window.location.replace("your url")
})
```

you could read more about [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) here